# How to set duplex (two-sided printing) printing on boot - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing

In Ubuntu 22.04, I have to set by default double sided printing, every time I boot into system. How to set it on boot, so that I don't need to change it every time I reboot system ?[image]

Comment: You probably need to stop the service that is responsible for printing (cups) before you can edit its config. I manually edit printers.conf often on servers and the alteration is always reversed unless I stop cups 1st.

Comment: This may depend on the printer and the printer driver you are using. For example, if it is one of the supported HP printers, you may want to install the utilities `hplip` and `hplip-gui` and then run `hp-setup`.

Comment: @user68186 it's a Toshiba printer

Comment: @Rinzwind  Restarting computer doesn't count as stoping the cups service ?

Comment: Please add the printer details in your question. Also include of and how you installed any printer driver.

Comment: @DanielWiczew yes but from what I notice on our servers is that cups will recreate the config file from what it has in memory when cups is stopped so it overwrites any outstanding alterations done while cups was active. No idea why it works like that :P